# What is an example of $f \in L^1(\mathbf{R})$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(nx)$ converges a.e. but is not in $L^1(\mathbf{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

what is an example of $f \in L^1(\mathbf{R})$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(nx)$ converges a.e. but is not in $L^1(\mathbf{R})$?

Context: This question appeared on an old qualifying exam.

I tried something like $\sin(x)/x$ but that didn't work.  Nothing else is coming to me.

Comment: Try something with compact support.

Comment: $f(x) = (e^{-x})_{ x > 0}$ which gives $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(nx) = \left(\frac{1}{e^x - 1}\right)_{x > 0}$ which is not $L^1$ because around $x = 0$ : $\frac{1}{e^x - 1} \sim 1/x$. so yes as Daniel Fischer said any $L^1$ function which is $> C$ on $[0;1]$ will give  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(nx) > C/x$ when $x \to 0^+$

Answer (score 1):

Try $f(x):=I_{[0,1]}(x)$, i.e. $f$ is a box of height 1 over the interval $[0,1]$. Then
$$f(nx)=I_{[0,1]}(nx)=I_{[0,1/n]}(x)$$
is a box of height 1 over the interval $[0,1/n]$. Then the sum $\sum f(nx)$ converges for every $x\ne0$ (since the sum terminates for every $x\ne0$), while the sum of the areas is
$
1 + \frac12 + \frac13 +\frac14 +\cdots
$.